# Convert Serial number to Date in q/ KDB and update to new column

Tags: kdb

**data**: contains the below columns whereas tenor serial number which should be converted to date YYYY.MM.DD by adding a new column to same data

| Class | RIC | Tenor | Product |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| OTC | AAAA | "42088" | Bond:Bonds:Sovin |
| OTC | ASD | "42095" | Bond:Bonds:Sovin |
| OTC | AABP | "5M" | Certified |
| OTC | DBSF | "1M" | Certified |

After change it should look like
product like "Bond:Bonds*"  - new column will contain value currently in 'tenor' column but in date format
not product like "Bond:Bonds*"  - new EndDate column will be null

| Class | RIC | Tenor | Product | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| OTC | AAAA | "" | Bond:Bonds:Sovin | 2015.03.26 |
| OTC | ASD | "" | Bond:Bonds:Sovin | 2015.01.04 |
| OTC | AABP | "5M" | Certified | 0Nd |
| OTC | DBSF | "1M" | Certified | 0Nd |

Comment: How does 42088 maps to 2015.03.26, while 42095 (greater) maps to 2015.01.04 (earlier date)?

Answer (score 1):

Are the dates in your expected output correct? It looks like the Tenor string indicates the number of days since 1899.12.31. If so, here's one way to obtain the result:

```
q)update EndDate:1899.12.31+"I"$Tenor from t where Product like"Bond:Bonds*"
class ric  Tenor   Product          EndDate
----------------------------------------------
OTC   AAA  "42088" Bond:Bonds:Sovin 2015.03.26
OTC   ASD  "42095" Bond:Bonds:Sovin 2015.04.02
OTC   AABP "5M"    Certified
OTC   DBSF "1M"    Certified
```

Comment: Excel offset time for KDB is 1899.12.30 and there is other condition as well which is product which are not like "Bond:Bonds:*" should also be updated as null i.e. "" aforementioned in the question table. Trying to apply the both in single query.

Answer (score 1):

Tenor looks to be excel based date so I think your expected output is wrong.

kdb dates start at `2000.01.01`. Checking excel needs to be offset by `1899.12.30`

Edit: the exact offset may need to be adjusted by you to what you expect but you get the idea of what is required

```
q)update EndDate:1899.12.30+"J"$tenor from t
tenor   EndDate
------------------
"42088" 2015.03.25
"42095" 2015.04.01
"5M"
"1M"
```

Edit: To make tenor null for "Bond:Bonds*":

Because Tenor is a string(i.e. nested list of chars) you need to create a list of same length as what is returned by the where. You can do this with `count[i]#enlist ""`

```
q)update Tenor:count[i]#enlist "", EndDate:1899.12.30+"J"$Tenor from t where Product like "Bond:Bonds*"
Class RIC  Tenor Product          EndDate
--------------------------------------------
OTC   AAAA ""    Bond:Bonds:Sovin 2015.03.25
OTC   ASD  ""    Bond:Bonds:Sovin 2015.04.01
OTC   AABP "5M"  Certified
OTC   DBSF "1M"  Certified
q)
```

Comment: Excel offset time for KDB is 1899.12.30 and there is other condition as well which is product which are not like "Bond:Bonds:*" should also be updated as null i.e. aforementioned in the question table. Trying to apply the both in single query.

Comment: The empty cells in endDate should be filled up with 0Nd for not product like "Bond:Bonds:*".  Tried updating the same with above query but still shows up as empty cells. Where I'm making wrong here?

Answer (score -1):

`update endDate:count[i]#enlist 0Nd from t where not Product like "Bond:Bonds*"`

You could try updating the same

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).